# Deploy to Windows Embedded Compact 7 yields "The bootstrap could not be loaded"

Tags: compact-framework, windows-embedded-compact

Here's the setup:

I'm trying to connect / deploy to a Motorola  Windows Embedded Compact 7 device from VS 2008.  The development machine VM is Windows XP (it has tools and SDKs going back to eVC3 on it that will not run on anything newer).  It is therefore running ActiveSync as opposed to WMDC.  Basic RAPI seems to be working as I can browse the device file system, ect via ActiveSync.  This developemnt system works successfully with dozens of other devices, but this might be the first CE 7 device.  And again, the error message was simply "The bootstrap could not be loaded".

I'd appreciate any tips on getting a successful connection to the CE 7 device working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. The solution for me was to install the SDK for the pda. Mine was MC32N0.
You can find the sdk [here](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=95849&redirectForm=search&searchQuery=%3FsearchType%3Dsimple%26searchTerm%3Dpsdk)